# dynamic ssis package

Tags: sql, ssis

I need to create SSIS package for importing files from ftp server to table on Data Lake. The problem is that files can have different columns. For example File1 can have A,B,C,D,E columns, next file can have A,B,C just, next A,B,C,D,E,F and so on. What is the best way to approach this problem?
I m talking about different columns for source file and same destination table.

Thanks

Comment: Do TABS have the same data?

Comment: You mentioned "same destination table" in question and "need to change destination table" in below answer. ???

Comment: no destination table is the same just if there is new columns in source file we need to add those columns and append to existing destination table

Answer (score 1):

Look into BiML, which dynamically creates packages based on meta data.

Comment: I need to change destination table if there is new columns in file.

Comment: I don't know if something like that is built into BiML, but you could do it with a script that runs before the BiML creates the dataflows.

Comment: so with script task i can change destination flat file if there is new columns?
Scenario: i upload file1 with 3 columns in source, file2 has 5 columns and i need to upload this file at same source, like append function.

Comment: You can definitely do this in a script task.  I don't know enough about how BiML works with flat file destinations to know if BiML can do this in a dataflow.   Probably you could use BiML to create a script destination component that could do this.

Answer (score 0):

1. Add an Object Variable
2. Add a data flow:
3. Use this script component to get column names:

[image: Script Component]

3.5 You might want to add a condition split or derived columns to monkey with the output.

4. Load the records into a recordset destination (use variable created in #1)
5. Add a ForEach and iterate through ADOObject
6. Add a variable to store each iteration
7. Create a variable to store SQL to pull your data set (Ex. "Select * from [" + variablecreatedInStep6 + "]"
8. Set your Source to use that variable

**MAKE SURE EVERYTHING IS DELAYED VALIDATION AS THIS IS ALL DYNAMIC**